# How do you print the code of a shell function in terminal?

Tags: zsh, function

I am using `zsh` and I have defined few utility shell function in some shell scripts, few of them called from `~/.zshrc`, so let's assume that we don't know the location of these functions. One function is:

```
function k.pstree.n {
    if [ "$1" != "" ]
    then
        pstree -p | grep -C3 "$1"
    else
        printf "  Please specify the name of the process you want to show!\n"
    fi
}
```

How can I print the code of that shell function?

I can think of a search & grep like:

```
find $(pwd) -name "*sh*" -type f -printf "\"%p\"\n" | xargs grep -C5 "k.pstree.n"
```

but this assumes that I roughly know the location which is not true here.

Comment: Following jimmij answer, the bash equivalent and zsh valid is `declare -f`, answered in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916856/can-bash-show-a-functions-definition).

In my case `declare -f k.pstree.n`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is built-in command `functions` in `zsh` for this purpose

```
functions k.pstree.n
```

For example in case of my `preexec` function:

```
$ functions preexec

preexec () {
    local cmd=${1:-}
    cmd=${cmd//\\/\\\\} 
    [[ "$TERM" =~ screen* ]] && cmd="S $cmd" 
    inf=$(print -Pn "%n@%m: %3~") 
    print -n "\e]2;$cmd $inf\a"
    cmd_start=$SECONDS 
}
```

Or use `typeset -fp function_name` which has the benefit of also working in `ksh`, `bash` and `yash`.

In `zsh`, the function definition is also available in the `$functions` special associative array (the key is the function name, the value the function body).

Comment: Another option is `typeset -f` what basically do the same as `functions`, but works in bash too.

Comment: `typeset` is obsolete, use `declare` instead

Comment: A possible problem with the use of `typeset`/`declare` in `bash` is that older versions (<3.2) have stricter naming constraints than allowed in creation of functions: it denies a name containing "." (and other non-alphanums) if you want just that named function shown.

Comment: @Costas `declare` is specific to bash, `typeset` has the advantage of also working in ksh and zsh.

Answer (score 2):

you can use which command :

```
$ which k.pstree.n
```